# Keyup contains filtering to block results

Tags: javascript, jquery, filtering, keyup

I have an html document with the field to filter text in blocks. Here is my code:

**JS:**

```
    $('#search-input').on('keyup', function() {

        var filter = $(this).val();

        var results = $('#icons section > .fontawesome-icon-list > .fa-hover:Contains("' + filter + '")');

        console.log(results);

        $('#results .row').html(results);
        $('#results').show();

    });
```

The filtered data is output in block **#results .row**.

The script works correctly only the first time (the first event 'keyup'). How to make so that at every event 'keyup' it filter the data correctly?

Comment: You should be declaring those vars outside of the function.

Comment: So is the keyup being called? Is the filter line returning anything?

Answer (score 1):

You need to clone the results:

```
var results = $('#icons section > .fontawesome-icon-list > .fa-hover:Contains("' + filter + '")').clone();
```